# Show 1 factory (individual) on page when factoryname is clicked

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, show, records

i have a searchfunction for factories. when i search for a factory and click on the name (a hyperlink) i want to show the individual factory on a new page.

You can see it here: http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/home/searchresults

The view for this link is:

```
<div id="bigcontent">
<h2>Zoekresultaten:</h2>
<br /> <br />
<table>
<tr><th>Bedrijf</th><th>Adres</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Plaats</th><th>Website</th><th>Email</th></tr>
<hr>
<br /> <br />

 <?php foreach($query as $item):?>
 <tr>
  <td><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/showindividueel/<?php echo $item->idbedrijven?>"><?= $item->Bedrijfsnaam   ?></td>
   <td><?= $item->Adres ?></td>
    <td><?= $item->Postcode ?></td>
    <td><?= $item->Plaats ?></td>
    <td><?= $item->Website ?></td>
     <td><?= $item->Email ?></td>
     </tr>
 <?php endforeach;?>

</table>

<br /> <br />
<hr>
<br />
<<<a href="<?php echo base_url('home/search') ?>">Terug</a>
</div>
```

The controller function:

```
    function showindividueel($id)
    {
        $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_result($id);
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('table_individual',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

My model function:

```
function get_result($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('bedrijven');

    $this->db->where('idbedrijven', $id);
    $result = $this->db->get();
    return $result; 
}
```

My view to show the individual factory:

```
<div id="bigcontent">
<table>
<tr><th>Adres</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Plaats</th><th>Website</th><th>Email</th></tr>
<hr>
<br /> <br />

 <?php foreach($query as $item):?>
   <tr>
 <td><?= $item->Bedrijfsnaam ?></td>
 <td><?= $item->Adres ?></td>
 <td><?= $item->Postcode ?></td>
 <td><?= $item->Plaats ?></td>
 <td><?= $item->Website ?></td>
 <td><?= $item->Email ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php endforeach;?>

  </table>
</div>
```

I get the error shown here: http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/home/showindividueel/1

My factory table has as the primary key idbedrijven. with auto-increment.

what am i missing?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return $result->result();
```

In the model.